# Iterate custom class, Read Table

Tags: c#, linq

I have little easy problem. Currently, I am not much familiar with `linq` and `generics`. I'm trying to read data from `people.txt` file which contains properties of people and convert to `Person` class.  (example first line: `John Male Chicago 23`)(name, gender, city, age)(they are separate by `" "`)

Also, group them by same city; order by age.

```
public class person 
{ 
    public string name;
    public string gender;
    public string city;
    public int age; 
}

static void Main() 
{
    person[] peoplelist;

    var SameCityBoston = from person in peoplelist
                         where person.city = "Boston"
                         select person;

    var OrderAge = peoplelist.OrderBy(person => person.Age);
}

public class PersonEnumerable : IEnumerable<person> 
{
    public PersonEnumerable(string path) {...} //read data
    public IEnumerator<person> GetEnumerator(){ } //how to iterate this.
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need separate Enumerable class?
You can create method that will read file and return list of persons:

```
    public List<person> ReadPersons(string path)
    {
        List<person> list = new List<person>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            // You can use different method to convert lien to person
            var parts = line.Split(' ');
            list.Add(new person { name = parts[0], gender = parts[1], city = parts[2], age = int.Parse(parts[3]) });
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Than you can choose what you want:

```
 List<person> peoplelist = ReadPersons(path);

 var SameCityBoston = peoplelist.Where(x => x.city == "Boston");
 var OrderAge = peoplelist.OrderBy(x => x.age);
```

Comment: For the sake of using concise LINQ (since OP mentions using LINQ): `return File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line => line.Split(' ')).Select(parts => new Person() { Name = parts[0], ... });` But it's functionally equal to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to read data from `people.txt` file which contains properties
>   of people and convert to `Person` class

If you would like to read all lines from text file, use [File.ReadAllLines method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string path = @"c:\MyData\person.txt";
List<person> persons = FileReadAllLines(path)
    .Select(x=> new person
    {
        name = x.Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0],
        gender = x.Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1],
        city = x.Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2],
        age = int.Parse(x.Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3])
    })
    .ToList();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom constructor to person like this

```
public person(string s)
{
    string[] split = s.Split(' ');
    name = s[0];
    //and so on
}
```

then you just need to implement GetEnumerator()

```
public IEnumerator<person> GetEnumerator()
{
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
    while(!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        yield return new person(file.ReadLine());
    }
}
```